# Meteo station point data to raster interpolation in Python, pandas and geopandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas, metpy, kriging

I'm looking for assistance to solve a spatial Kriging problem in Python (or any other solution you might suggest) that involves integrating multiple variables from the columns of the same dataframe and a digital elevation model (DEM). I'm trying to use libraries like scikit-gstat, PyKrige, or similar ones to perform a prediction that works as interpolation based on a defined dimension through a GeoDataFrame or a raster. Weather data is contained in a dataframe, and I want to predict data from one specific column using the others to enhance the prediction. However, I'm facing some challenges in properly integrating all the information. Here's an overview of the challenges I'm encountering:

Here's an example of the data structure I have access to:

index                       name       lat       lon  h_sea      B11001  
0                 Bologna urbana  11.32879  44.50075   78.0  227.705601
1                 Ferrara urbana  11.62114  44.83250   26.0  198.142529
2                  Finale Emilia  11.28402  44.83906   12.0  177.565454
3                  Forli' urbana  12.04182  44.22039   51.0  223.155397
4             Granarolo Faentino  11.92193  44.36161   15.0  228.395657
5                      Martorano  12.26798  44.16614   25.0  218.178186
6                  Modena urbana  10.91699  44.65639   73.0  228.691860
7                   Parma urbana  10.33049  44.80800   79.0  204.097518
8                Piacenza urbana   9.67965  45.05492   71.0  209.698362
9      Reggio nell'Emilia urbana  10.63370  44.69781   72.0  204.874015
10                 Rimini urbana  12.57354  44.05919   16.0  217.934321
11          San Pietro Capofiume  11.62264  44.65378   11.0  223.010690
index    B11002  B12101_C     B13003
0      1.916224  5.802898  74.152932
1      2.229462  5.061348  79.357680
2      1.811290  3.764022  80.027007
3      1.848094  5.767242  76.988415
4      2.143994  4.222029  85.696343
5      2.224553  5.377731  80.022900
6      2.077067  4.990518  74.163372
7      1.365618  5.175278  76.194010
8      1.345687  4.610513  74.584989
9      1.280448  5.221846  73.971977
10     2.137484  6.226524  74.544494
11     2.285721  3.531839  84.784460

Here an example of code I tried to use but not working

```
def geodataframe_to_kriging_raster(geodataframe, column_name, pixel_size, covariates, dem, variogram_model="linear"):

    if geodataframe.crs != dem.crs:
        area_bounds_gdf = dem.to_crs(geodataframe.crs)
        print('Modificato il sistema di riferimento')

    file_bounds = box(*dem.bounds)
    min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = file_bounds.bounds
    width = int((max_x - min_x) / pixel_size)
    height = int((max_y - min_y) / pixel_size)
    transform = from_origin(min_x, max_y, pixel_size, pixel_size)

    coordinates = np.column_stack((geodataframe.geometry.x, geodataframe.geometry.y))
    data = geodataframe[column_name].values
    
    dem_values = dem.read(1)

    OK = UniversalKriging(
        coordinates[:, 0],
        coordinates[:, 1],
        data,
        variogram_model=variogram_model,
        verbose=False,
        enable_plotting=False,
        drift_terms=covariates,
        external_drift=dem_values
    )
    z, _ = OK.execute("grid", np.linspace(min_x, max_x, width), np.linspace(max_y, min_y, height))

    return z, transform
```

I have a geospatial dataset in GeoDataFrame format that includes a variable of interest (e.g., weather data) and some covariates (other related variables).

I want to perform spatial Kriging to estimate the value of the variable of interest on a raster grid.

I also want to include a digital elevation model (DEM) as an external covariate in Kriging to influence the estimation of the variable of interest.

I've tried to use libraries like scikit-gstat and PyKrige, but I'm experiencing difficulties in integrating covariates and DEM into the Kriging process. Specifically, I'm trying to define the experimental variogram for each variable, but I'm struggling with the correct configuration.

I've already attempted different variations of code, but I keep receiving errors related to the configuration of experimental variograms and the specification of covariates and DEM in the Kriging process.

I'm seeking assistance and advice on the correct setup to perform this spatial Kriging while considering all the involved variables. Any help, suggestions, or example code would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Understanding how to interpolate the weather data taking into account other factors compared to the fact that I want to prefer. For example, I want to predire the wind, but I must also take into account humidity, wind direction, pressure etc. Understand also how to do it perhaps with important historical series, that is every hour